# How to use regex in SaltStack to comment out entire line

Tags: regex, salt-stack

**Background**:

I'd like to comment out the following line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/rhel-swap   swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

After reading the [Salt documentation on salt.states.file.comment](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html), I came up with this in my `.sls`:

```
Permanently Disable Swap Memory:
  file.comment:
    - name: /etc/fstab
    - regex: swap
```

(I also tried `^swap`.)

**The output**:

```
      ID: Permanently Disable Swap Memory on Cassandra Nodes
Function: file.comment
    Name: /etc/fstab
  Result: True
 Comment: Commented lines successfully
 Started: 08:13:09.809454
Duration: 25.587 ms
 Changes:
          ----------
          /etc/fstab:
              updated
```

**The result**: The line still isn't commented out. Notice the last line in my `/etc/fstab` after the Salt install:

```
/dev/mapper/rhel-root   /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=69cb98f5-5325-4168-a28c-c1219081ae16 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rhel-home   /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rhel-swap   swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
~
```

**Questions**:

- Why wouldn't this line be commented out, despite the successful output from Salt?
- The documentation says I need to include the leading `^` anchor, but doesn't that match the beginning of the line? How would I get a regex working that uses `^` and also matches the word `swap`, which occurs in the middle of the line?

**Other info**:

- Environment: Red Hat 7

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why it wasn't working originally, but here's the regex that worked: `^(\/).*swap.*$`. This matches any line starting with `/` and containing the word `swap`.

Here's the full salt step:

```
Permanently Disable Swap Memory:
  file.comment:
    - name: /etc/fstab
    - regex: ^(\/).*swap.*$
```